# Excel: column formula with conditions

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I want to find the slope and intercept of a column of data, but I want to include an IF function that looks at another column and only counts the data if the condition is met.

Example:

```
1   54  23
2   34  52
2   25  93
2   13  53
1   88  54
```

I want to find the SLOPE and INTERCEPT of these variables ONLY WHEN the type is 2.

I know the syntax would be `=SLOPE(B:B)` but how do I add conditionals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your slope calculation done manually would be `=SLOPE(B2:B4,C2:C4)`, to filter to just those where `A` gives a value of 2 would be `=SLOPE(IF(A1:A5=2,B1:B5),IF(A1:A5=2,C1:C5))`, entered as an array formula. The `IF` just filters the ranges you provided when used as an array formula like this.

Comment: That did it. I needed to remember that as it's a static calculation but I was dragging it down the column, I had to ensure the references were fixed, not relative. I also did this in Google Sheets and the process wasn't as expensive as I expected it to be.